# Ctrl + Shift being swallowed

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

I've noticed today that something is capturing `ctrl`+`shift` intermittently with Ubuntu 20.04.4. I've discovered it because it looks like 75% of the time that my application is being unfocused (and hence the caret disappearing). This is affecting me in Sublime Text and VSCode and is quite frustrating.

Does anyone know how I can track down what the cause is, as I'm not really sure where to look to diagnose? I'm not sure of anything obvious that I've changed, though I did dabble with changing the workspace settings in Gnome Tweaks the other day.

Below is an example where a popup is appearing correctly, but then on a number of presses the caret disappears and nothing happens :(

[image]

I've confirmed that this isn't a fault with the keyboard by testing on another device. This exhibits no problems. I've also confirmed that this is not unique to the keyboard, as the built in laptop keyboard has the same problem.

*Update*
I have discovered something interesting. The problem is not intermittent, but is dependent on the order of key presses.

If I press `ctrl` then `shift` then `f`, then my search will popup correctly (in whatever app I'm in, e.g. Sublime, VSCode, Terminal).
I've noticed the terminal renders a `☐` when I press `ctrl` and then changes back to a `■` when I press `shift`.

[image]

If I press `shift` then `ctrl` - at that point the cursor changes in
a different way, to a `☐`, and pressing `f` won't do anything.

[image]

Comment: Please eleminate hardware failure first. Test using another OS or an Ubuntu live Installation USB using the **Try Ubuntu** option. Update the question indicating if the problem persists there as well. If it does, then replace your keyboard.

Comment: @user68186 thanks, have done so

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard on this device also? To eliminate the possibility of any problem with the keyboard controller in the motherboard of the problem computer, do the Live USB (**Try Ubuntu**) test as well.

Comment: @user68186 I've tested with the in-built keyboard that exhibits the same behaviour. I've also added some more info I've discovered.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, what is it a duplicate of?

Comment: Sorry @C.S.Cameron, thought I selected the duplicate when I flagged it. Wasn't obviously a duplicate when I originally posted